# Is using '--force' or '--legacy-peer-deps' would harm in long run?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am currently working on a react-native project and want to install native-base library but getting the following error ...

```js
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: demo@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from native-base@3.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/native-base
npm ERR!     native-base@"3.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (react-dom)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-native@0.64.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
PS C:\Users\Bishal Ghosh\Desktop\React-Native\demo> npm install native-base --save
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: demo@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from native-base@3.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/native-base
npm ERR!     native-base@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (react-dom)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-native@0.64.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"^0.64.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from native-base@3.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/native-base
npm ERR!     native-base@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Bishal Ghosh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bishal Ghosh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-02T06_48_53_257Z-debug.log
```

I tried solving the issue by removing my node_modules folder but didn't work. Then, I installed using **--legacy-peer-deps**, it gets installed. So, now I would like to know will it run in long-run if I install my dependencies using those flags??

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would harm but I can't tell you that as a fact.
What I can do is to tell how I solved similar issue I had.

I assume that you are using npm version 7.X.X (you can check it with `npm --version` 
If that indeed the case this error will be shown almost on every dependency you'll try to install so what I did was to downgrade back to npm 6.

To do that all you need to do is run the following command in your command line:

```
npm install -g npm@6.14.13
```

Comment: But downgrading my npm version will restrict me to take the advantages of latest features.....

Comment: which are..? more strict dependency tree management..? well it's just a recommendation.. you can keep using those work arounds.. but note that you'll might end up force installing of something has nothing to do with the dependencies tree

Comment: Will it be safe installing packages forcefully?

Comment: well you are forcing the installation. if it was always safe I assume it was the default and there was no need to "force"